# Add and start cron task in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, cron, ubuntu-16.04, cron-task

I tried to add new cron task under root in Ubuntu:

```
* * * * * python /home/o/Desktop/Python/init.py >/dev/null 2>&1
```

After I did restart service like:

```
sudo service cron restart
```

It does not work in result, why?

Comment: When I do: `crontab -l` it says there are no cron tasks

Comment: `service cron status` says that cron works

Comment: Path to file is correct, Python is installed

Comment: Yes I have `/etc/cron.d`. I mean I work under root

Comment: Now I change cron line to `* * * * * python /home/oleg/Desktop/Python/init.py`. Still is not working

Comment: When I do restart cron I get this massage: `Failed to add /run/systemd/ask-password to directory watch: No space left on device`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161127/discussion-between-benjamin-w-and-jessie).